# Erro ao carregar a extensão PDO

Tags: php, magento, pdo

Fiz a transição do meu site utilizando [magento](/questions/tagged/magento) mas no novo servidor ele acusa o seguinte erro:

> The PDO extension is required for this adapter but the extension is not loaded

*Obs: Já reconfigurei o php.ini.*

Comment: Qual versão do php vc usava antes e qual usa agora? o pdo aparece habilitado no `phpinfo()` ?

Comment: Mensagem relata que a extensão PDO não está habilitada, verifique isso junto a sua hospedagem!!!

Comment: eu coloquei as extensões .so no php.ini, só isso não deveria ser suficiente?

Comment: Você precisa conferir se o arquivo da extensão existe, o erro diz q ele não foi carregado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue o link para o magento-check aonde verifica tudo o que é necessário para rodar o magento e reporta caso alguma falha:

```
https://gist.github.com/atomicpages/4383809
```

Após isto é necessario caso falte algum modulo instala-lo ou carrega-lo.

Fico a disposição para mais informações.

Comment: Entrei em contato com a equipe de suporte da prestadora de serviço e eles liberaram alguma coisa lá que estava atrapalhando. Obrigado.